# Post video to user's Youtube channel with permission from the User?

Tags: facebook, youtube, permissions, youtube-api

Is it possible to post a video to a user's youtube channel with their permission? Basically the equivalent of a Facebook app posting a video to a user's timeline after they have authorized the app to do so. 
I was hoping Google+ would have integration similar to facebook's, but couldn't find anything linking app authorization back to Youtube. 
Any help or light would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you'll be wanting to use [Oauth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps).